# Installing BeEF Mint-17.2

Tags: linux-mint, json

I want to install BeEF, but when following their [steps](https://github.com/beefproject/beef/wiki/Installation) there is some errors.

1) - RVM is not installed.

2) doing source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm gets an error:

```
raph@raph-xxxxxxxxx ~/beef $ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
bash: /home/raph/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

3) error when doing bundle install

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot   continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Have you installed RVM? Have you installed the json gem?

Comment: That was my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mrt, from mibbit:
RVM had to be installed in order to install BeEF.
Following their [steps](https://rvm.io/rvm/install), I was able to install RVM. Next steps was to `gem install bundler`.
Finally, install BeEF with the following steps:

```
git clone git://github.com/beefproject/beef.git
cd beef
bundle install
ruby beef
```